# How to perform Binary Tree Postorder Traversal?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, binary-tree, tree-traversal

The code will give a result of 4 2 1 3 6 5 7. How do I code it to transform into a postorder traversal?

```
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
    
def func1(nums):
    if not nums:
        return None
    mid_val = len(nums)//2
    node = TreeNode(nums[mid_val])
    node.left = func1(nums[:mid_val])
    node.right = func1(nums[mid_val+1:])
    return node

def func2(node): 
    if not node: 
        return      
    print(node.val)
    func2(node.left) 
    func2(node.right)   

result = func1([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
func2(result)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post-order Graph Traversal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488968/post-order-graph-traversal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the post-order tree-traversal, first the left child node, then the right child node, and finally the parent node are printed. Accordingly, if you line up the same scenario for your func2 function, you should edit your code like this.

```
def func2(node):
    if not node:
        return
    func2(node.left)
    func2(node.right)
    print(node.val)
```

Comment: oh right i thought of implementing another function to transform it to postorder, perfect, thanks! well I could write that as a new function too

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Is valid for non-binary trees too.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,jobName):
        self.job = jobName
        self.children = []

def postorder(node):
    if len(node.children) != 0:
        for child in node.children:
            postorder(child)
    print(node.job)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tree = Node("0")
    tree.children.append(Node("00"))
    tree.children.append(Node("01"))
    tree.children.append(Node("02"))
    tree.children[0].children.append(Node("000"))
    tree.children[0].children.append(Node("001"))
    tree.children[0].children[1].children.append(Node("0010"))
    tree.children[0].children.append(Node("002"))
    tree.children[0].children[2].children.append(Node("0020"))

    postorder(tree)
```

000
0010
001
0020
002
00
01
02
0

Comment: Why check `len(node.children) != 0`?

Comment: (You could try to make this generic: 1) [document](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) 2) drop "business attribute" job from `Node` 3) pass a function to `postorder()` to call for every node (optionally 4) add ["aliases"](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) `left` & `right`).)

Comment: len(node.children) != 0 is for stopping when there is no child for current node. Sorry for the delay:)

Comment: `len(node.children) != 0 is for …` there wouldn't be a single trip though the loop without this pre-check if `children` was empty.